# Chapter 5: Automate the boring stuff

Tags: python

I'm attempting to learn Python from the PDF: Automate the boring stuff. I've previously learnt some basic C in University, but am trying to learn Python as it seems more useful.

The code below is very close to working (having compared with other answers on this forum), but something I am doing in addToInventory function seems to be destroying the function. I suspect that it has something to do with the weird way I am using the for loop, due to my previous C training.

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
print("Inventory:")
item_total = 0
for k, v in inventory.items():
    print(str(v) +" "+ k)
    item_total=item_total+v
print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))


def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in range(0,len(addedItems)-1):
        inventory.setdefault(addedItems[i],0)
        inventory[addedItems[i]]=inventory[addedItems[i]]+1

 
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

Many thanks in advance to the community here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "destroying the function" and provide an example of what you _expect_ its behavior to be, versus what it _currently is_?

Comment: Your `addToInventory` *modifies* `inventory`, but you are trying to use it as if it returned a value (it returns `None`). Change the call from `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` to just `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is modifying the array in-place, so there is no need for further assignment. The line can simply read:

```
addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

You can also add `return inventory` to your function, although it is preferable to do the in-place modification.

As for the rest of your code, `range` in Python is not inclusive of the upper bound, so it will not reach the last element of the list. Remove the `-1` in your for loop.

Comment: I don't think it is helpful for functions which do in-place modification on an object to also return that object. There is little gain, because the caller will _already_ have the object reference which was passed in the function parameters, and adding a return value may obscure the fact that the function modifies the object. Compare `list.sort`, which returns `None`.

Comment: @alaniwi modified my answer based on your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

(1) Your addToInventory function already modifies the variable inv (since lists in Python are mutable and are passed by reference), so you can change the line `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` to `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)`

(2) You can add the return statement: `return inventory` to the end of the addToInventory function (because at the moment this function doesn't return anything - meaning that the line `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` sets the variable inv equal to `NoneType`, which isn't the behavior you want).